# Getting the entire output from subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I'm getting a slightly weird result from calling subprocess.Popen that I suspect has a lot to do with me being brand-new to Python.

```
args = [ 'cscript', '%USERPROFILE%\\tools\\jslint.js','%USERPROFILE%\\tools\\jslint.js' ]
p = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
```

Results in output like the following (the trailing double \r\n is there in case it's important)

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.\r\n\r\n
```

If I run that command from an interactive Python shell it looks like this

```
>>> args = ['cscript', '%USERPROFILE%\\tools\\jslint.js', '%USERPROFILE%\\tools\jslint.js']
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
Lint at line 5631 character 17: Unexpected /*member 'OpenTextFile'.
f = fso.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(0), 1),

...

Lint at line 5649 character 17: Unexpected /*member 'Quit'.
WScript.Quit(1);
```

So there's all the output I really care about, but if I dump the value of the "p" variable I just set up...

```
>>> p
'Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8\r\nCopyright (C) Microsoft Corpor
ation. All rights reserved.\r\n\r\n'
>>>
```

Where'd all that data I want end up going? It definitely didn't end up in "p". Looks like it's going to stdout, but I didn't I explictly tell it not to do that?

I'm running this on Windows 7 x64 with Python 2.6.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it going to stderr? Try redirecting:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: it should be `p,e = Popen(...).communicate()` otherwise you're dumping stderr away

Comment: Not the way I wrote it - stderr is being redirected to stdout. You need to specify `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` if you want separate streams.

Comment: If I just called .communicate() w/o redirecting stderr it wasn't in the tuple I got back. Redirecting stderr did the trick though, thanks @SimonJ!

Comment: Don't use `shell=True` in Windows.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably going to `stderr`, as SimonJ suggested.

Also, the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) say not to use `shell=True` in Windows for your case:

> The executable argument specifies the
>   program to execute. It is very seldom
>   needed: Usually, the program to
>   execute is defined by the args
>   argument. If shell=True, the
>   executable argument specifies which
>   shell to use. On Unix, the default
>   shell is /bin/sh. On Windows, the
>   default shell is specified by the
>   COMSPEC environment variable. The only
>   reason you would need to specify
>   shell=True on Windows is where the
>   command you wish to execute is
>   actually built in to the shell, eg
>   dir, copy. You don’t need shell=True
>   to run a batch file, nor to run a
>   console-based executable.

---

Later: oh wait. Are you using the shell to get those environment variables expanded? Okay, I take it back: you do need the `shell=True`.