# subprocess.Popen() IO redirect

Tags: python, popen

Trying to redirect a subprocess' output to a file.

server.py:

```
while 1:
    print "Count " + str(count)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    count = count + 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Laucher:

```
cmd = './server.py >temp.txt'
args = shlex.split(cmd)
server = subprocess.Popen( args )
```

The output appear on screen, `temp.txt` remains empty.
What am I doing wrong?

As background I am trying to capture the output of a program that has already been written.

I cannot use:

```
server = subprocess.Popen(
                [exe_name],
                stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

as the program may not flush.
Instead I was going to redirect output through a fifo. This works fine if I manually launch server.py but obviously not if I `Popen()` cause redirect doesnt work.
`ps -aux` shows that `server.py` was launched correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect output with subprocess in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4965159/608639)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Altenatively, you can use the `stdout` parameter with a file object:

```
with open('temp.txt', 'w') as output:
    server = subprocess.Popen('./server.py', stdout=output)
    server.communicate()
```

As explained in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed program’s standard input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively. Valid values are PIPE, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and None.

Comment: That works. Communicate would block reader until the server terminates but now that I can redirect I can send server output to a fifo.

Comment: no need to call `.communicate()` here. `subprocess.check_call('command', stdout=file)` works.

Answer (score 9):

Output redirection with ">" is a feature of shells - by default, `subprocess.Popen` doesn't instantiate one. This should work:

```
server = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True)
```

Comment: Using `shell=True` is not the preferred way, unless it's necessary (and here it is not)

Comment: @wim This seems to be an important comment, but there is no explanation why.