# Piping data from python to an external command

Tags: python, subprocess, external-process, piping

I've read everything there is on subprocess.Popen but I think I'm missing something.

I need to be able to execute a unix program which reads a data stream from a list created in the python script and write the result of that program to a file. From the bash prompt I do this all the time with no problem but now I am trying to to this from within a python script which preprocesses some binary files and a lot of data before coming to this stage.

Lets look at a simple example not including all the preprocessing:

```
import sys
from pylab import *
from subprocess import *
from shlex import split

# some arbitrary x,y points
points = [(11,31),(13,33),(15,37),(16,35),(17,38),(18,39.55)]

commandline = 'my_unix_prog option1 option2 .... > outfile'
command = split(commandline)

process = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
print process.communicate(str(points))
```

The way this would be executed in bash is:

```
echo "11 31
      13 33
      15 37
      16 35
      17 38
      18 39.55" | my_unix_prog option1 option2 .... > outfile
```

The way the data is fed into the unix prog is important as well, I should be formatted in 2 columns separated by whitespace.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: in the `command` you have the output redirected to `outfile` but then you try to read it into your program using `communicate`.  Where do you want the output to go?

Comment: Using '>' is not the way to redirect output to a file, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902206/subprocess-popen-io-redirect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLVED!

With the help of [Dhara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1196900/dhara) and [xhainingx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1013719/xhainingx) I was able to figure this out:

```
import sys
from pylab import *
from subprocess import *
from shlex import split

# some arbitrary x,y points
points = [(11,31),(13,33),(15,37),(16,35),(17,38),(18,39.55)]

commandline = 'my_unix_prog option1 option2 ....'
command = split(commandline)

process = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=open('outfile', 'w'), stderr=PIPE)
for p in points:
    process.stdin.write(str(p[0]) + ' ' + str(p[1]) + '\n')

print process.communicate()
```

This works very well, thanks.

Comment: I'd also recommend that you create the file object outside the call the Popen so you can later call `.close()` on it when you and your subprocess are through with it

Answer (score 1):

how about something like

```
for p in points:
    process.stdin.write(str(p[0]) + ' ' + str(p[1]) + '\n')

print process.communicate()
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct about that (both of you) but I think my problems begin before that: I use the '>' redirection but this is shell redirection and is not valid.

Comment: @Shahar you can use the `shell=True` argument in your Popen constructor to allow the shell redirection, but then `communicate` won't return anything for stdout.  Another option is to open a file  `f=open('outfile', 'w')` and then instead of `PIPE` use `stdout=f`.  I'm not sure what the problem is now

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your input to communicate correctly.

`str` will keep the special characters when you print your list of tuples which isn't what you want.

```
>>> print str([(1,2), (3,4)]) 
[(1,2), (3,4)]
```

Try this:

```
print process.communicate("\n".join(["%s %s"%(x[0], x[1]) for x in points])
```