# bash or python script to read binary data from STDIN and save to a file

Tags: python, bash, ssh, binary, stdin

Before anyone tells me, I completely realize what I'm trying to do is absurd but I have my reasons.

I have a server on which I can write a script (bash or python). The script needs to accept binary data from STDIN and save it to a file. To be precise, the binary data is a WAV file.

What I am doing is using an iOS app called Workflow. The app will let me record an audio file and then send it as STDIN input to a script that it will run over SSH. So my script needs to take that STDIN input and save it to a file.

Any ideas/thoughts? I'm completely lost on where to start.

Comment: the tool is called [`cat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat)

Comment: To write binary from stdin with bash : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19043/how-can-i-handle-raw-binary-data-in-a-bash-pipe

Comment: related: [Reproduce the unix cat command in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11532980/4279). Here's [`cat.py` in Python 3](https://gist.github.com/zed/cda879d141081e5764bd)

Comment: `cat - > $file` to be exact, @Jakuje This will copy stdin to a file, even if it's binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To save stdin to a file on a POSIXy system:

1. make sure stdin is opened in the binary mode
2. check whether [fadvise](https://chris-lamb.co.uk/projects/python-fadvise) improves the time performance in your case e.g., see [`copyfileobj()` in contrib](https://github.com/lamby/python-fadvise/blob/c0e7fdf92a09c24b6f93132e803bfd975ed39ed5/contrib/copyfileobj-fadvise.py)
3. read chunks from stdin and write them to the file

In general, you could also [try `os.sendfile()` if stdin might be redirected from a file (mmap-able file descriptor)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14411471/4279) (it doesn't apply in your case).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import shutil
import sys

with os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb') as input_file,\
     open(sys.argv[1], 'wb') as output_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(input_file, output_file)
```

Example:

```
$ python -msave_stdin output_file
```

that should be equivalent to:

```
$ cat >| output_file
```

Comment: Note that this closes the file descriptor of STDIN which could lead to issues. To avoid it, don't open "stdin" using the "with" context but do: `input_file = os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb')`

Comment: right, the copy is done successfully but STDIN (file descriptor 0) is closed. Execute `os.system(f'ls -la /proc/{os.getpid()}/fd')` before and after the block, and you will see my point. A (long running) program with closed FD=0 could experience strange things. One example is that if you open a file afterwards, it could get FD=0, because it's free. And if we're not careful and assume that FD=0 is always "stdin", we may get confused.

Answer (score 3):

To read from stdin in python :

```
import sys
input = sys.stdin.read()
```

To write binary to a file:

```
with open('name_of_file_here','wb') as output:
   output.write(input)
```

Where 'wb' sends for write, in binary mode.

Comment: I should have mentioned, the read() function will read everything coming from stdin, until it encounters EOT, which is \x04 (in hex) or Ctrl+D.
To stay safe you can check how many bytes you want to pipe into stdin, and then use sys.stdin.read(number_of_bytes)

Comment: are you talking about Windows? Piping binary data on Windows is a non-trivial task e.g., see [what happens in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33959798/4279). Piping binary data is trivial on POSIX (it doesn't stop on `\x04` or anything else -- don't confuse what you type in terminal (that might be affected  by the terminal settings) and the data that is piped via application's stdin).

Comment: I was talking about POSIX. 
Just tested it, and you are absolutely right. Not sure why I thought that... Thanks!

Comment: to avoid corrupting newlines (if `os.linesep != b'\n'`) or for Python 3 compatibility, open stdin in binary mode. To support large files, read stdin in chunks.