# Python using os.walk to run exiftool on all files separately in directory

Tags: python, linux, exiftool

I'm looking to use Python to iterate through all the files in a folder and run the `exiftool` command on each file, so in the end I should have `x` amount of files each with their own `exiftool` output to run `grep` commands on.

Currently I have this code (I made it from pseudocode I took down whilst at a lecture, so it's probably not that accurate)

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
import os
import subprocess
import sys
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print("echo", os.path.join(root, name))
        subprocess.call(["exiftool", os.path.join(root, name)])
```

Comment: I fixed up your psuedocode to at least be runnable.

Comment: And with that edit, I probably solved your question already. Try running it now..

Comment: Thanks a ton, letting it run now (will take a bit of time but it's running so hopefully all goes well :D).

Comment: Any ideas on how I would change this to execute exiftool so it gives me a seperate txt file output for each file it goes through?

Comment: Have you checked the `exiftool` documentation to see how it could do that? Or does it produce the information on stdout and you need to redirect it?

Comment: Normally with exiftool you specify the filetype and if you want to store the result then put it into a textfile like so: exiftool * .jpg > exifjpgoutput.txt.  I want to do an output for each file in a txt - so it would go exiftool "x file" > "xfile.txt"

Comment: [Python: How to Redirect Output with Subprocess?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4965159) you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using python, you could simply use an [existing Python library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead) that allows you to read Exif tags, and avoid all error-prone parsing.

Comment: The OP simply wanted to have the files produced by `exiftool` to grep against..

Comment: no, he wants to run exiftool against all files. Your (@MartijnPieters) solution is probably correct; however, he asked for any hints, so I hope this is helpful to him.