# Extra line in the terminal introduced by Popen

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I have the following script that attempts to submit a job to the PBS queue.

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess

inpfile="sim.input"
qscript="run.sh"

#2.1 create a directory to launch the script from
dir="test"
os.system("mkdir {}".format(dir))
os.system("cp {} {} {}".format(qscript,inpfile,dir))


#2.2 launch the simulation
subprocess.Popen(["qsub",qscript],cwd=dir)
```

The script works, but after I hit `Enter`, I get in the terminal an empty line, so I have to hit `Enter` again to recover my prompt. This doesn't happen if I do `subprocess.call()`. So, the question is how to get rid of that `newline`? The following is what I see in the terminal:

```
dude@machine$ python submit01.py 
dude@machine$ 3463.machine.com

dude@machine$
```

Edit: the script `run.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -N job
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -V
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
pwd
```

`sim.input` can be any file.

Comment: Please provide the scripts for reproducing your results.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6482200/3653831)

The empty line for the subprocess.Popen() comes from me not specifying the standard output. If that's not specified, there is an empty line in the terminal which is, as far as I can tell, harmless. So, the code could be:

```
with open("output.txt","w") as out:
    #2.2 launch the simulation
    subprocess.Popen(["qsub",qscript],cwd=dir,stdout=out)
```

and will not give an empty line.