# Running subprocess.call from python script

Tags: python-2.7, shell, command, subprocess, external

I have a functionality where I need to run a command inside a python script. From another answer, I figured `call from subprocess module` is the safest way. But, I am unable to work through it. I am using python 2.7

This is a smaller version of what I am trying :

```
import subprocess
a = "echo hello"
subprocess.call([a])
```

It gives me the following error :

```
 subprocess.call([a])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am unable to figure out why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the commands as a *string* or a *list* but not as a string in a list, otherwise the system is trying to run the `echo hello` process (which doesn't exist, obviously, which explains the `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` error message). Passing it as a string requires `shell=True` on some systems.

And `shell=True` is also required with shell built-ins like the `echo` command (which has a non built-in version in `/bin` on some systems, just to add to the confusion)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["echo","hello"],shell=True)
```

For non built-in commands (I assume that `echo` is just a test here), avoid `shell=True`, since it adds an unnecessary shell layer which degrades startup performance, and is prone to code injection (`echo hello; rm -rf everything_on_disk)`

To run your favorite editor for instance, you can do:

```
subprocess.call(["emacs","readme.txt"])
```

Comment: Hi, just a follow up question : I want to write a string src to a file. So, this is how I should do it?

     inputFile = "nameInput"
    c1 = ["echo" ,src, ">>", inputFile] 
    call(c1, shell=True)

Comment: Follow up questions aren't really on-topic here, but check this one it answers perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965159/python-how-to-redirect-output-with-subprocess

Comment: ya, just wanted to be sure if what I understood was right. Thanks :)

Comment: with my answer + all the info on the site (google search, don't use site search as it sucks) you'll find everything.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written has issues, subprocess.call takes in a list where the first element of the list is the command. In your case it is `echo` and `hello` is your argument it should be the next value in the list. So your code should look like this.

```
import subprocess

a = [ "echo","hello"]
subprocess.call(a)
```