# How do I run and open a .py file in a tkinter gui in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, subprocess, pycharm

I have coded a gui with buttons and when I press one button I want it to run a .py script that displays a graph, so the graph has to open in a different view altogether.

The `.py` file for the graph runs perfectly on its own but I am trying to implement it into my GUI upon clicking a button (I've used Tkinter) - I have done this using subprocess for a different `.py` file, but the output is saved instead of being printed at the bottom.

So I am unsure how to do a like a python test.py upon clicking a button for it to open in a separate window.

The second button should be able to run a .py file, but the output should be shown in a text file instead of printing at the bottom of the console.

This is what I have so far:

```
        def visualise():
            #with open(" .png", "r") as output:
                command = ("python test.py")
                p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
                p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
                print 'completed'
```

buttongraph = Tkinter.Button(self, text="generate graph", command=visualise)
buttongraph.pack()

(The print does print but the command does not execute and I also removed the `stderr`, because the output line of the code does not work. I was just playing around with it.)

Comment: Umm, why are you sending a SIGINT signal to the process? SIGINT interrupts the process...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to Redirect Output with Subprocess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965159/python-how-to-redirect-output-with-subprocess)

Comment: @Aran-Fey thank youuuuu lol it works