# Is there any other altrenative to ">" in BASH w/ Python Subprocess

Tags: python, bash, docker, subprocess, kali-linux

I am trying to print out my outputs into a log file, I am using **python** with **subprocess** to do so. But when I use **>** in code, I am getting error like:

```
+ klm.py scan /home '>' /home/userA/out/home_03-30-2022_11-07-32.log

2022-03-30 09:09:21,074 ERROR > does not exist
```

Here is the code I am running:

`subprocess.run(['sudo', 'docker', 'run', '-it', '--rm', '-w', '/workdir', '-v', f'{pwd}:/workdir:ro', 'docker-local.abc.xyz.xyz.name.com/klm', 'klm.py', 'scan', f"{pwd}", ">", f'/home/userA/out{directory}_{date_time}.log'])`

Whenever I use the command itself directly into the terminal, command is working working without any error and creating the .log files, I assume this is error coming from subprocess or python side.

```
> directory variable is a for loop of list elements -> DIRECTORIES = [/home, /root, etc]

> datetime just a string -> date_time 

> pwd is -> pwd = os.getcwd()

> I don't know if it is useful info but I am using Kali Linux for this
```

Comment: The redirection is a shell feature. Use `shell=True` and give the command line as a string. Also read https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations

Comment: I fell like you should remove ' ' from around the `>` operator

Comment: Yes: [How to redirect output with subprocess in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965159/how-to-redirect-output-with-subprocess-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to show a standard output redirection on a simpler command. It prints the date and time to a file. First using shell's redirection and then without the shell's help (`shell=False` is the default)

```
import subprocess

# with shell redirection
subprocess.run(['date >out1.txt'], shell=True)

# without shell
with open('out2.txt', 'w') as out:
    subprocess.run(['date'], stdout=out)
```

Note: the documentation asks you to read the [Security Considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) before using `shell=True`.