# Listing the contents of crontab using Python's subproces reports unknown user

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, subprocess

When I use

```
sudo -u tango crontab -l >> /tmp/crontango.txt
```

within the terminal it works fine.

Doing the following in python

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['sudo', '-u tango', 'crontab', '-l', '>>', '/tmp/crontango.txt'])
```

leads to an error

> sudo: unknown user:  tango

I tried to reconfigure the arguments without any success.

How do I copy my crontab to a textfile using a python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate all arguments and [catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965159/how-to-redirect-output-with-subprocess-in-python) the output like so:

```
with open('/tmp/crontango.txt', 'a') as f:
    subprocess.run(['sudo', '-u', 'tango', 'crontab', '-l'], stdout=f)
```