# using python subprocess's call function, but not getting output file

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using python subprocess library to run command line in python file.
After importing the library, I used following code to store the output

```
call(["python", "make.py", ">", "data"])
```

But for some reason, I didn't get data file

Comment: I would say this answer is closer to what he wants: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3982683/2073595. Still, definitely a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the `stdout` , check the official document [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

```
    import subprocess
    my_output_file = open("/home/user/output", "a")
    subprocess.call(["python", "hello.py"],stdout=my_output_file)
    my_output_file.close()
```